# ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND with any other files in project - how to not specify .js?

Tags: node.js, typescript, apollo

Getting this error with files in subfolders if I don't specify .js.  This works fine in my library project, but fails here even with "type: module" in package.json.  It fails not at compile, but only at runtime.

error:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/home/me/code/means-of-production/server-new/dist/resolvers/libraries' imported from /home/me/code/means-of-production/server-new/dist/index.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:231:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:850:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1058:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:164:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:838:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:419:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Node.js v19.4.0

Process finished with exit code 1
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "server-new",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc",
    "start": "npm run compile && node ./dist/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/server": "^4.3.0",
    "@meansofproduction/domain": "^4.0.0",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.11.18",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDirs": ["src"],
    "outDir": "dist",
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "types": ["node"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "sourceRoot": "src"
  }
}
```

This fails:

```
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
import { startStandaloneServer } from '@apollo/server/standalone';
import {allLibraries} from "./resolvers/libraries";
import * as fs from "fs";

const typeDefs = fs.readFileSync('schema.graphql').toString()
```

But this works:

```
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
import { startStandaloneServer } from '@apollo/server/standalone';
import {allLibraries} from "./resolvers/libraries.js";
import * as fs from "fs";

const typeDefs = fs.readFileSync('schema.graphql').toString()
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand the concern. If you are using esm then file extensions are required in import specifiers per the spec.

Comment: Ah ok, so it's only with common.js that you can ignore them in Typescript?

Comment: Like you said, the project compiles fine, and this is a **runtime** issue. See https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#mandatory-file-extensions

Comment: Hmmm ok - it's odd because it works fine in the library project part of this larger project, and don't really understand why?

Comment: You'd have to provide a reproducible example if you want more help.